# How do I center this logo using CSS?

Tags: css, center

I have a site here: http://donniewalker.com/jen/

That I've been trying to center with CSS, but nothing I've tried seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any code to show? Can you reproduce your issue on something like **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**?

Comment: Please add your code to your question, so it remains relevant for others once you get it fixed.

Comment: Remove the float, and set left and right margins to `auto` on `div.logo`.

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language.  Please don't use it's tag for questions relating to graphical logos.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `float: left;` and all margins from `.header-v5 #header .logo` and add `margin: 31px auto;`. So it looks like this:

```
.header-v5 #header .logo {
   margin: 31px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your div of class logo get rid of where you have

```
margin-top: 31px;, margin-right: 0px, margin-bottom: 31px;, margin-left: 0px;
```

and add

```
margin: 31px auto 31px;
```

also, you need to remove the `float: left` that is applied to .header-v5 #header .logo

Comment: Just fyi, you only need `margin: 31px auto` as that shorthand says "top and bottom: 31px, left and right: auto"

Comment: Well, none of that worked. This is what I have: .header-v5 #header .logo {
   margin: 31px auto;
}

.logo {
margin: 31px auto;
}

Comment: and I removed all the logo related float: left, from:                  #header-sticky .logo,
#header .logo {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 31px 0;
}

body #header-sticky.sticky-header .logo {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-height: 65px;
  width: auto;
}

Comment: In the Chrome Developer Console, this is all I had to do: http://screencast.com/t/0IbUhu6jfq  It will be difficult to help any further unless you post code.